# GROUP BY every "n" records (Keeping first record's ID)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a large database with information like this:

```
date         sku    sales
2019-02-13   123    10
2019-02-14   123    10
2019-02-15   123    10
2019-02-16   123    10
2019-02-17   123    10
2019-02-18   123    10
2019-02-19   123    10
2019-02-20   123    10
2019-02-21   456    10
2019-02-22   456    10
```

I would like to Query the table but with GROUP BY by every 7 days, so I would get:

```
begin_date   sku    sales  week
2019-02-13   123    70     1     
2019-02-20   123    10     2     
2019-02-21   456    20     1
```

So I´m GROUPING BY every 7 records per SKU and keeping the first date for each sku. One important issue is that actual table does not have records sorted by date or sku

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and actually works ... )

```
#standardSQL
WITH skus AS (
  SELECT sku, MIN(dt) AS start_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY sku
) 
SELECT 
  MIN(dt) begin_date, 
  sku, 
  SUM(sales) sales, 
  DIV(DATE_DIFF(dt, start_date, DAY) + 7, 7) week
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
JOIN skus s USING(sku)
GROUP BY sku, week
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-13' dt, '123' sku, 10 sales UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-14', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-15', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-16', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-17', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-18', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-19', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-20', '123', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-21', '456', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-22', '456', 10 
), skus AS (
  SELECT sku, MIN(dt) AS start_date
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY sku
) 
SELECT 
  MIN(dt) begin_date, 
  sku, 
  SUM(sales) sales, 
  DIV(DATE_DIFF(dt, start_date, DAY) + 7, 7) week
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
JOIN skus s USING(sku)
GROUP BY sku, week
-- ORDER BY sku, week
```

with result

```
Row begin_date  sku sales   week     
1   2019-02-13  123 70      1    
2   2019-02-20  123 10      2    
3   2019-02-21  456 20      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the first day for each sku and then use that information:

```
select date_add(mindate, interval floor(date_diff(date, mindate, day) / 7) * 7 day) as week_start
       sku, sum(sales) as sales,
       1 + floor(date_diff(date, mindate, day) / 7) as weeks
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by sku) as mindate
      from t
     ) t
group by weeks, week_start;
```